# Is there a way of capturing debug messages in C# and then outputting them to a separate window?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, tracelistener

I have spent 3 days looking this up and I cannot find a solid answer. I want to capture debug messages and than output them to a list log. I am trying to do this in C#. Would love some help from the community to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I have put this as a comment rather than an answer...  I wanted the facility to log to a window, and I even wanted it to work remotely.  I implemented a Logging class that then transmitted it as UDP.  This had the nice side effect of having a variety of 3rd-party tools to "listen" and watch the log (e.g. anything that could listen to Udp).

Comment: Do you mean all "debug messages", or just the debug messages output by your application through the System.Diagnostics.Debug class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, sure that's possible. Debug output is not limited to being displayed in the Output Window.

All you have to do is write a custom listener and add it to the [`Debug.Listeners` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.listeners.aspx). You can find the full documentation about adding trace listeners [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7.aspx).

The only thing to watch out for is that the listeners are shared for debug and trace output, so if you add one, you'll receive both types of messages.

If that sounds like too much work and you just need a quick-and-dirty solution, you can download the free [DebugView utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) from Sysinternals. This neat little tool is a separate application that you run, and it listens to all debugging output from all of the programs installed on the machine. If you use this, you won't even have to change a single line of code in your application—all of the output send to `Debug.Write` will show up in the DebugView window.

Alternatively, if you're looking for something long-term that you could perhaps even ship with your application, I would encourage you to investigate adding a logging feature. There are lots of good open source libraries that provide this functionality, and it can be invaluable out in the field when your app is deployed to systems with unknown configurations.

Comment: The goal is to capture the messages and than log them to a list. Once I have that setup, I am trying to make it so that you can use check boxes to turn off messages that you don't want to see or help you sort and filter certain messages.

Comment: @GabeTHEGeek Then it sounds like to me you want a comprehensive logging framework for your application. They have all of that kind of stuff built in. You won't have to write a bunch of your own code to categorize and filter out messages. [Some possible options are discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126540/what-is-your-net-logging-framework-of-choice), and you can probably find a bunch more if you Google. I don't have a preference or a specific one that I could recommend, but if you pick a popular one, you should be in good hands.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. This def helps me get on the right path. The plan is to ship it with our application so you are very correct.

Comment: When we speak of "debug output messages" in C# we generally mean `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`.  (And we could not possibly mean `P/Invoke OutputDebugString()`, because if you use this function, you ain't gonna see anything in the output window of visual studio when debugging a dotnet process.) So, are you sure that the DebugView utility will capture messages generated via `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as logging goes, [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is solid and easy to use. You can add it to your project via NuGet (if you don't know what NuGet is, check it out: it's really nice). It allows you to log more or less wherever you want (console, file, mail, db ... )

Website contains good documentation and examples.